# Python Scatter Plot to smooth Line plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plotly

I have a large number of data frames and trying to make a scatterplot with a smooth line; my code seems to be correct for a small set of data but not for large data sets. Is there any efficient way to have a smooth plot?
Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from scipy.interpolate import make_interp_spline

df = {'A': [ 2,8,9,7,2,2,10,13,9,5,2],
      'B': [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
x = df['B']
y = df['A']
X_Y_Spline = make_interp_spline(x, y)
X_ = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 5000000)
Y_ = X_Y_Spline(X_)
 
# Plotting the Graph
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x= x,
    y= y,
    name = 'Real'
), row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x= X_,
    y= Y_,
    name = 'Smooth'   
), row=2, col=1)

fig.update_layout(
    title = "Real and smooth Plots "
)

fig.show()
```

and my output is as follows[its seems correct only for small set of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hX9z.png)

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it is correct for small datasets and not for larger ones? What are the results you are getting vs what are the expected results? Can you provide a simple script that displays the issue you're encountering?

Comment: I don't know if this will help you solve your problem, but Plotly has the ability to draw trend lines. See [here](https://plotly.com/python/linear-fits/#locally-weighted-scatterplot-smoothing-lowess) for details